# I am trying to identify this font used in RSK Group's logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can anyone identify the font in the graphic below?

[image: font]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, it looks like [Franklin Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/franklin-gothic/).

Comment: It does indeed look like [ITC Franklin Gothic Std Heavy](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/franklin-gothic/std-heavy/) but with the top of the "K" modified.

Comment: The "K" really looks like the K from Arial Black - have they combined the typefaces?

Comment: Arial Black borrowed a lot from Franklin. Could be a character swap or a little lisguided modification.

Answer (score 3):

The K is Arial Black =) . And then the tracking to -175 .... or -200 .    Must be a value between them I'm sure =].   Good luck.

Comment: It's not Arial's capital R, unless they've done a custom modification to it...

Comment: Tell you what though, the K really looks like Arial Black's!  Is it possible they've used Franklin Gothic for the RS and Arial Black for the K???  Is that even a good idea??

Comment: I used franklin gothic for the first 2 letters and arial black for the K and it looks pretty good. It didn't even cross my mind that the designer could have used 2 fonts. Thanks everyone for their help. Brilliant

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE Super](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114143320/http://www.fontpark.net:80/en/font/berthold-akzidenz-grotesk-super/#)

[image: Berthold Akzidenz Grotesk BE Super sample]

Comment: Very very similar, but the S is different. Good call though.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely two different typefaces. The 'K' does not fit the overall angles found in the other letters. Not a great idea, but it happens every now and then.

Comment: I down voted because I felt that you didn't really try to answer the question. I think this should be a comment.